# finding minimum number $k$-subsets containing all pairs of elements of $[n] := \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $A_1,A_2, \dots, A_m$ be $k$-subsets (each of size $k$) of $[n] := \{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$ such that for every pair $i, j \, (1\le i < j \le n)$ there exists some $A_l \, (1\le l \le m)$ such that $\{i, j\} \in A_l$.

What is the minimum value of $m$ and how do we enumerate/generate a family of subsets $A_1, A_2, A_3 , \dots, A_m$?

(This is not [2916733](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916733/k-subsets-with-some-pair-containing-every-element))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m_{n,k} $ be the number you are looking for.  There is a recursive relation between $m_{n,k} $ and $ m_{(n-1),k}$. Write $n-1=q(k-1)+r $ where $ 0\leq r<k-1$. Note that  when you add a new element $a_{n} $ to the set $B_{n-1}:=\{a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1}\} $ there are $n-1 $ sets $\{i,j\}\subseteq B_{n-1} $ containing $a_n $ so you have to "add those pairs" to your old sets $A_1,\cdots, A_{m_{n,k}} $. The minimum way of doing this is by adding the   $ k-$sets $\{a_{n+1},a_1,\cdots,a_{k-1}\}, \cdots, \{a_{n+1},a_1,\cdots,a_{qk-q}\}$ (there are $ q$ of them ) to your collection. Now you have to add a set cointaining all the remining $ r$  pairs (this is only one set because $ r<k-1$).  So $ m_{(n-1),k}+q+1=m_{n,k}$.

Now construct an especific example of the situation and use the previous relation to make a conjecture of the value of $ m_{n,k}$.

Comment: I suggest putting a comma between $n$ and $k$

Comment: @qwr Done. If I missed some please tell me or edit.

Comment: I don't think this gives a minimal value for $m$. I assumed you meant $q$ to be $q=\lfloor\frac{n-1}{k-1}\rfloor$. If we try this recursive relation for $n=5$, $k=3$, starting from the trivial case $n=k=3$ where $m=1$, we get $m_{5,3}=6$. However, I can construct as few as 4 subsets $A$ containing all pairs: ${(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (3, 4, 5)}$ so the actual value of $m_{5,3}=4$